# Pull data from REST API with a GET request in Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, rest, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am having a task in Airflow DAG, which uses requests library to fetch data from REST API. But I am getting the below exceptions which I am not able to figure out. I have tried the same logic with urllib3 as well, I am facing the same issue.

The code is pretty straight forward, which works from terminal but it is not working in Airflow

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

response = requests.get(api, auth=('user','password'))
```

```
[2021-02-10 20:55:16,499] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 852, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 332, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 852, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 332, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()

urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task

    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute

    return_value = self.execute_callable()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable

    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)

  File "**file_location**", line 92, in process_row

    response = requests.get(api, auth=('**user**', '**password**'))

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

[2021-02-10 20:55:26,311] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-02-10 20:55:26,311] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Comment: Airflow is not the issue here, the connection is just getting shutdown by remote. You should introduce retries to handle that exception.